# Three in a Row Check Bingo

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I'm new to programming and my friend gave me the following problem.

Bingo- given an array of arrays, write a function to check if there is a winner (either three one's in a row diagonally, straight down, etc.)

```
      var bingo = [
        [0,0,0],
        [0,0,0],
        [0,0,0]
        ];
```

I've been working to set it up like so.

```
      function winCheck(bingo) {
        for (var i = 0; i < bingo[i].length; i++) {
           if (/* ??????? */) {
              /*?????*/
           } else {
              /*?????*/
           }
        } 
      }
```

I'm not sure how to approach this. Do I need a loop within a loop? At my present knowledge I only know how to loop through a single array. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The matrix is always 3x3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so much code to do it the way you want, so make sure first: is it really necessary? If the size of array varies or unknown, we couldn't make any optimization and our function will drearily start with check all of horizontal lines:

```
function winCheck(bingo)
{
  // check for all values equals to 1 in any horizontal row:
  for (var i = 0; i < bingo.length; i++)
  {
    winner = true;

    for(var j=0; j < bingo[i].length; j++)
    {
      if(bingo[i][j] != 1)
      {
        winner=false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(winner)
      return true;
  }

  // now the same code for for vertical rows
  // . . .

  // and finally two simple loops to check diagonals
  // . . .

  return false;
}
```

But if the size of array is always 3 x 3, everything changes! We may run one single loop to check horizontal and vertical rows and finally if we have 1 in the middle cell, do additional checks for diagonals:

```
function winCheck(bingo)
{
  var winner = false;
  for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    if(winner = (bingo[i][0]==1) && (bingo[i][1]==1) && (bingo[i][2]==1))
      break;
    else if(winner = (bingo[0][i]==1) && (bingo[1][i]==1) && (bingo[2][i]==1))
      break;

  if(!winner)
    if(bingo[1][1]==1)
      if(!(winner = (bingo[0][0]==1) && (bingo[2][2]==1)))
        winner = (bingo[0][2]==1) && (bingo[2][0]==1);

   return winner;
 }
```

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra thanx! made a fix

Comment: if the matrix is n > 3 is still wrong based on this "either three one's in a row diagonally, straight down, etc."  Suppose this, n=4 and this is the first row: [1,1,1,0]

Comment: @Roberto De La Parra, may be you are right, but as I understand the word bingo, it is a single digit in each position of a row... So unless Jason clarify something I would keep my answer as is

Comment: Yes for clarification it just needed to be a single digit in each position in the row. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use nested loops for this like so

```
for(var i = 0; i < bingo.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < bingo[i].length; j++)
    {
        //do some stuff with bingo[i][j]
    }
}
```

feel free to ask if you need more help on the loop's body